# How to access value from the object within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can I access Name's value and assign it to an variable?

```
var arr = [
    {Name: "Jason", 
    Title: "Student", 
    Image: "asdf", 
    Status: "Happy"}
];
```

Comment: `arr` is an array. To access the first element in it, do `arr[0]`. Now to access the `Name` property, you can do `arr[0].Name`

Comment: You can access it by reading up on basic ways to access things in objects in JS, such as "dot notation". Start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors. Or something more general, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide. SO is not really oriented towards providing tutorials or elementary techniques--you'll need to find other ways to obtain that knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the element at index `0` of array using bracket notation, then access property name `Name` of object using dot or bracket notation

```
var arr = [
    {Name: "Jason", 
    Title: "Student", 
    Image: "asdf", 
    Status: "Happy"}
];

var name = arr[0].Name; // alternatively, `arr[0]["Name"]`
```

Comment: why was this downvoted? it's the correct answer with the correct explanation.

Comment: It's the correct answer to a question which is decidedly inappropriate for SO. We should not be encouraging people to use SO as a substitute for better ways to learn elementary concepts, which are covered in the first page of any tutorial. Most basic questions have already been answered, and so can be closed as duplicates to avoid cluttering up the site, but this one is **SO** basic that no-one (apparently) had ever thought to ask it before. If you are going to answer the question, at least you should point the OP to good learning resources, since he obviously has not found them yet.

Comment: @DerekFu See [Dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) , [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var [{Name: name}] = arr;
```

This uses ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

First, the outermost `[]` is a way of referring to an array on the right hand side (in this example, `arr`). Things placed within these square brackets (here's there's only one) refer to the first, second, and succeeding values of that array. So here, the `{Name: name}` portion refers to the first (0th) element of the array. In other words, it is equivalent to

```
var {Name: name} = arr[0];
```

The inner `{}` is a way of referring to objects and picking them apart. `{Name: name}` says to find the `Name` property of the object being picked apart. Then the `: name` part says to rename it to `name`. Since all this is occurring in the context of a `var` statement, the result is **declare a new variable with the name `name` and assign the value being picked out to it**.

Here's the more detailed sequence:

```
var            // Start a variable declaration 
  [            // Pick apart an array on the RHS, starting with 1st element
    {          // Pick apart an object
      Name     // Find the property named `Name` in that object
        :name  // Rename it; this is the variable that will be declared!
    }          // Done picking apart the object
  ]            // Done picking apart the array
  = arr;       // Specify the thing to deconstruct
```

Comment: New for this, this will return array of one element?

Comment: @HadiHassan No, it will declare a variable `name` with the value from `arr[0].Name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
    {Name: "Jason", 
    Title: "Student", 
    Image: "asdf", 
    Status: "Happy"}
];
var myname = arr[0]['Name'];
console.log(myname);
```